# Postgres transpose a row

Tags: sql, postgresql, unpivot

I have a table which looks like the following :-

```
a    b   c   d   e 
29  14  11  16   8
```

I want to transpose it to the following form, in Postgres:

```
a 29
b 14
c 11
d 16
e 8
```

I know I'm supposed to use the `pivot` operation to do this, but I can't figure out the right syntax to get this done.

Any help to get this done will be appreciated.

Comment: This looks to me like the EAV (Entity–Attribute–Value) data model which is usually considered sub-optimal and rudimentary being superseded by JSON for example.

Comment: the example row you see above is the result of an aggregate query, which I now have to transpose for further use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would simply be:

```
select 'a' as column_name, a as value from mytable
union all
select 'b' as column_name, b as value from mytable
union all
select 'c' as column_name, c as value from mytable
union all
select 'd' as column_name, d as value from mytable
union all
select 'e' as column_name, e as value from mytable
```

but with multiple rows in the table you don't see anymore, which `a` is related to which `b`, etc. So while this matches your request, you may want to think over, whether this is really what you want to do.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a lateral cross join:

```
select l.*
from the_table t
  cross join lateral (
     values ('a', a), ('b', b), ('c', c) ('d', d)
  ) as l(column_name, value);
```

Another option is to convert the row to a JSON value, then use `jsonb_each_text()` to extract the key value pairs. This is a bit more dynamic, but the downside is that you need to cast the values back to an integer:

```
select l.column_name,
       l.value::int as value
from the_table t
  cross join lateral jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(t)) as l(column_name, value);
```

If you have a primary (or unique) key column in the table, you might want to add that to the SELECT list (`select t.id, l.* ...`), so you know from which row each value came from.

Comment: @WitchKingofAngmar . . . This is the better solution.